# ng-if condition using angular js u-grid cell template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ui-grid, celltemplate

I am having radio button in my angularjs ui-grid, last updated radio button should enable if the values are same.

ng-checked="row.entity.value=\'A\'";

now am having two grid rows with same name

customer : A  //(here i  need radio button)
customer: A  //(not here) using ng-checked="row.entity.value=\'A\'";
customer:B
Customer: c

but radio button should enable for any one of the value

Comment: Condition for `ng-checked` should probably be `ng-checked="row.entity.value==\'A\'`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, but in multiple radio buttons Iam having same values like customer:A, emp1.  customer A,emp2 but Iam checking only first radio button, but the cell template shows both are checked. how to refersh cell template.